# Add my HtmlHelper dropdownlist into my jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-helper

Got some problem when adding my dropdownlist using MVC htmlhelper into some javascript code. It keep saying my syntax is error. So basically want I want to achieve is every time user click #lnk-addmore link, it will add additional dropdownlist. Here is my code:

```
$('#lnk-addmore').click(function () {
        $('#rowScopeWork').after(GenerateNewScopeWorkRow());

        return false;
    });

    function GenerateNewScopeWorkRow() {
        return ['<tr valign="top">',
                    '<td width="19%"></td>',
                    '<td colspan="3">',
                        '<div class="col-xs-6">',
                           @(Html.DropDownList("dd-selectType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Builders, "- Select One -", new { @class = "form-control" })),
                        '</div>',
                    '</td>',
                '</tr>',
        ].join('\n');
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Do you get it client side or on compiling?

Comment: Error message from my firebug, so its client.

Comment: Can you post the client code?

Comment: You need to surround the razor code with single quotes `'@(Html.DropDownList(....))',`